# What could I do to make my conditional format work in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Background: I am trying to keep a file to log the amount of hours I have performed a certain activity (e.g. practice my piano repertoire). I want to use an Excel sheet with conditional formatting to make some things more clear (e.g. highlight months as 'red' or 'green' based on practice hours).

So far, I have come up with the following structure-

[image]

I have been able to use a *sumif* function to calculate the number of hours I have practiced based on the date:

```
(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&D4,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D4,0)))
```

This will essentially tell me how many hours I practiced for that month. Running this formula on Nov-19 (cell D4) will give me 7.5, Dec-19 (cell D5) will give me 13.5, etc.

I want to use conditional formatting over the months to highlight them 'green' or 'red' if the practice hours are >=20 or <20. How can I write a rule to achieve this? I have tried some variations in creating a new rule, but none work...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your sumifs formula in other cells just like below:

```
2019    2020    2021
 7.5      12      12
   0      32      32
          43      43
          54      54
          23      23
           4       8
          12      21
          22       2
          13       3
          12      12
          22      22
```

For that use formula: SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&D4,$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(D4,0))

Then:

1. Select cell with your date Nov-19.
2. Go to Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule
3. From list select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. In text box write ={Address of 7.5 value}>=20
5. Use format as you want when clicking "Format..." button.

Go through points above again to format your cell when: {Address of 7.5 value} < 20

{Address of 7.5 value} can be e.g. H4.

When conditional formatting has been added, just use Format Painter from Home tab to other cells.

Hope it will help.

More information here: [LINK](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/highlight-excel-cells-based-on-the-value-of-another-cell/).

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this as well. I was wondering if there was a way without pasting my values in another cell and if I could do it inside the conditional format itself. If there's no way to do that, then this is what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired result you should add the Conditional Formats using these formulas:

```
= SUMIFS( B:B, A:A, ">=" & D4, A:A, "<=" & EOMONTH( D4, 0 ) ) < 20
= SUMIFS( B:B, A:A, ">=" & D4, A:A, "<=" & EOMONTH( D4, 0 ) ) >= 20
```

However after applying those two formulas your data will show in red not only the prior months for which you did not reach the targeted of hours of practice, but also the future months as they total hours add to zero, therefore defeating the purpose of  *“making things more clear” (see picture below)*:

[image]

Therefore it’s suggested to add another conditional format with this formula to correct that effect.

```
"= D4 > TODAY()"
```

**IMPLEMENTATION:**
Follow these steps to create the required Conditional Formats:
*Note: in order to show the effect of the conditional formats I’m using 10 instead of 20 as the target hours, change the formulas accordingly at implementation.*

1. Select the range `D4:D5,E4:E15,F4:F15`
2. Add the Conditional Format to ensure future moths are not highlighted. Use this formula, *do not set any format*.

   ```
   = D4 > TODAY()
   ```

[image]

3. Add the Conditional Format to ensure future moths are not highlighted. Use this formula, and set format\fill to Red.

   ```
   =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&D4,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D4,0))<10
   ```

   [image]
4. Add the Conditional Format to ensure future moths are not highlighted. Use this formula, and set format\fill to Green.

   ```
   =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&D4,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D4,0))>=10
   ```

[image]

5. Use the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager to ensure the format are in the correct order and that the `Stop is True` box is check for all of them.

   [image]